# Glossary and list of acronyms in the same page

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

Basically I have two lists (glossary and acronyms) that i want to merge into one section only, something like (List of terms AND acronyms)

Comment: Please provide a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) showing what you are doing now, and a description of how that differs from what you _want_ to do. In particular, how are you building the glossary and acronym lists?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: I'm building it using \printglossaries, the standard way, and it's printing in one page the glossary and the next page the acronyms, sorry for not posting the code but it's a bit  
fuzzy

Comment: Do you want to merge the two lists into a single list? In which case just omit the `acronym` package option. (I assume you're using the `glossaries` package since you have `\printglossaries`.) Or do you want two sections within a chapter? In which case use the `section` package option. To create a minimal working example, start with [minimalgls.tex](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/samples/minimalgls.tex) and replace the class with the one you're using.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `section` package option to change the sectioning command used by the glossaries. For example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[acronym,section]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},
description={a sample entry}}

\newacronym{aca}{aca}{a contrived acronym}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
A \gls{sample} entry and \gls{aca}. Second use: \gls{aca}.

Plurals: \glspl{sample}. Reset acronym\glsreset{aca}.
First use: \glspl{aca}. Second use: \glspl{aca}.

\chapter*{List of Terms and Acronyms}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Resulting image]

Or you can just combine the main glossary with the list of acronyms by removing the `acronym` package option:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},
description={a sample entry}}

\newacronym{aca}{aca}{a contrived acronym}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
A \gls{sample} entry and \gls{aca}. Second use: \gls{aca}.

Plurals: \glspl{sample}. Reset acronym\glsreset{aca}.
First use: \glspl{aca}. Second use: \glspl{aca}.

\printglossary[title={List of Terms and Acronyms}]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Resulting image]